# Can't UPDATE using Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, visual-studio-2013

```
try
{
    ContentDB contentDB = context.ContentDBs.FirstOrDefault(i => i.KeyID == KeyID);

    contentDB = contentDBUpdated;

    ChangeSet cs = context.GetChangeSet();
    Console.Write("Total changes to ContractorDB: {0}", cs);

    context.SubmitChanges();  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

What I am doing here is this passing all my new data inside the object which is called `contentDBUpdated` it has all the parameters set. Then I set that object to and object from context which is `contentDB` and then `.SubmitChanges()`

It keeps telling me

> Inserts: 0, Deletes: 0, Updates: 0

I don't understand why because when I look through debugger at `contentDB` object it did get new values.

Comment: `contentDB = contentDBUpdated`, you are simply changing the object reference, not changing its content.

Comment: You are only changing the reference. Take a look into `ShallowCopy` and `DeepCopy` for ways to copy the property values of one object to the properties of another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set/update the object like:

```
contentDB = contentDBUpdated;
```

This will only copy the reference, so now `contentDB` holds the same reference as `contentDBUpdate`, and the original context attached to `contentDB` is lost.

You can set properties like:

```
contentDB.Name = contentDBUpdate.Name;
contentDB.SomeOtherProperty = contentDBUpdate.SomeOtherProperty;
```

and then update will work.